# lodash - Add object to another object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have user object

```
{first: "john", last: "doe"}
```

How can I attach details object

```
{car: 'corolla', color: 'silver'}
```

So that the output would be

```
  {first: "john", last: "doe", details:  {car: 'corolla', color: 'silver'} }
```

I have tried _.merge, _.assign and both flat details object and I end up with

```
  {first: "john", last: "doe", car: 'corolla', color: 'silver'}
```

Comment: Why use a framework when you can assign it directly? `user.details = details`?

Comment: make your code simple. Or its for training purposes?  `var user = {first: "john", last: "doe"};  user.details = {car: 'corolla', color: 'silver'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the `details` object to `details` property of `user`:

```js
var user = {first: "john", last: "doe"};
var details = {car: 'corolla', color: 'silver'};
user.details = details;
console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 4):

With plain Javascript, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var object = { first: "john", last: "doe" } ,
    details = { car: 'corolla', color: 'silver' };
    
Object.assign(object, { details });

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

In context of lodash , you can use _.assign(user,{details});

```
var user = {first: "john", last: "doe"};
var details = {car: 'corolla', color: 'silver'};

console.log(_.assign(user,{details}));
```